# Store either constant or non constant reference within the same class template

Tags: c++, constants

The example below is degenerate because I would like to learn about the concept.

Let's say we would like to have a 1-element `view` of an array.

My question is how to make it work with both `const` and `non-const` objects.

I know why the second block in the code below does not compile but I don't know how to organize the code to serve both cases.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class View {
 private:
  const std::size_t index_;
  T &t_;
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;

 public:
  View(T &t, std::size_t index) : t_{t}, index_{index} {}

  const value_type &value() const { return t_[index_]; }
  value_type &value() { return t_[index_]; }
};

int main() {
  using Array = std::array<int, 2>;

  // The block below works
  {
    Array array{0, 0};
    View<Array> view(array, 0);
    view.value() = 5;
    assert(array[0] == 5);
  }

  // The block below gives a compilation error
  {
    const Array array{5, 5};
    View<Array> view(array, 0);
    assert(view.value() == 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting, and with which compiler?

Comment: [Tangent] If you have something you call a *view*, why does it allow for modifications?  views should be read only which make it really easy to implement as you just hold a const reference.

Comment: is it on purpose that `View<std::array<int,2>>` is a different type than eg `View<std::array<int,3>>`, or would you be fine with `View` being parametrized with the element type? (btw I agree your `View` isnt really a view in the sense the term is usually used)

Comment: What is the purpose of this `View`? It looks like a complex version of `T&`

Comment: @MooingDuck learning, imho OP is quite clear about the purpose

Comment: Agree, the word view is confusing. Alternative is a `Slice`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class View {
 private:
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;

  T &t_;
  const std::size_t index_;

 public:
  View(T &t, std::size_t index) : t_{t}, index_{index} {}

  const value_type &value() const { return t_[index_]; }

  template<class Arr = T, class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<Arr>::value>::type>
  value_type &value() { return t_[index_]; }
};

int main() {
  using Array = std::array<int, 2>;

  // The block below works
  {
    Array array{0, 0};
    View<Array> view(array, 0);
    view.value() = 5;
    assert(array[0] == 5);
  }

  // The block below gives a compilation error
  {
    const Array array{5, 5};
    View<const Array> view(array, 0);
    assert(view.value() == 5);
  }
}
```

If you give the `View` a `const Array` you also have to specify a `const Array` as template argument.

But then returning a non-`const` reference with `value()` doesn't work anymore, so we disable this function with SFINAE, if the array type is `const`.

PS: You wouldn't have the last problem if your class named `View` were indeed what one would expect under a view, i.e. non-modifiying and not even having a method returning a non-`const` reference.

Comment: I agree that a word `view` confused a lot of people. Maybe `Slice` would be better. But indeed, I just wanted to learn about the idea.

Comment: @TruLa, it is a ["span"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Comment: @TruLa another way around this would be to declare the second array as `const std::array<const int, 2>`.